# How to require wordpress login to view a subdirectory within the wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, subdirectory

I have my Wordpress site at **xroads.com**

Inside, there is a folder called "_warehouse" which contains a php CRUD app

Is it possible to require the same login page I use for the Wordpress site to view the _warehouse directory?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*If the user already has an account in WordPress*:

Redirect the user to the login form. Use `wp_login_url` with the `$redirect` parameter to set where they go after logging in:

```
$loginUrl = wp_login_url( home_url('_warehouse') );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

Then use the `wp_login` action to manually authenticate the user in your application:

```
add_action('wp_login', function($username, $user) {
    // Log user into external application
}, 10, 2);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

Actually setting the user as "logged in" is going to depend on how your external application is setup. It could be as simple as setting a session variable and then checking if that is set in your warehouse app.

Comment: Will give this a try and let you know how it went!
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possible solution (use at your own risk).

Create a `.htaccess` file in the `_warehouse` directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ wplogin.php [NC,L]
```

This will redirect all requests for files that exist in `_warehouse` and any subdirectories to `_warehouse/wplogin.php`

Create `_warehouse/wplogin.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

// Edit this path to include wp-load.php from your WordPress directory
require_once '../wp-load.php';

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    // if user is not logged in, set redirect URI, show WP login
    $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    require_once '../wordpress/wp-login.php';
    exit;
} else {
    // user is logged into wordpress - show the requsted file.
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Lastly, and very important, add this to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

This is because WordPress will set cookies with a path specified.  This would prevent the login cookies from being recognized in `_warehouse`.

And as I said, use at your own risk.  It is not perfect but is probably the quickest way to achieve what you want and will handle many cases.

Note: it doesn't deal with directories with no index.  If Apache `Options +Indexes` is on, someone may be able to see directory listings in `_warehouse` but if they try to access one it will show the login page.

Comment: Be careful if you're using user input to include files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Comment: @mtinsley Definitely a concern, but the .htaccess rewrite ensures that the REQUEST_URI is a valid file on the server so $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should be pretty sane and the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in front will eliminate a lot of exploits.  For added safely, the PHP script could sanitize REQUEST_URI and do additional checks on it.

Comment: @drew My current app htaccess has the Rewrite Rule like this  

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`  

App was made on Slim PHP and using Active Record. Should I add the one you provided additionally?

Comment: @KenRyan In that case even better, just leave the rewrite as is and add the `wplogin.php` code to the beginning of your current `index.php` code above where the slimphp app gets bootstrapped.  You can even get rid of the `else` block and just leave the is_user_logged_in and exit code.  Basically you want to check if they are logged in, if not show wp-login and exit, otherwise let the index.php run as usual

Comment: @drew Do I include the cookie path as well?   I changed '../wordpress/wp-login.php' on the code to my wordpress folder site called 'xroads'         The console says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  Am I missing something?

Comment: @KenRyan The cookie path *has* to go in your wp-config.php file in the xroads directory.  The server error may be due to the file path of the require_once call being wrong.  You will likely have to check the server error logs for the exact reason.